# How can we know the frequency at which messages are being published in ROS2?

Tags: ros, ros2, frequency, dds

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How can we know the frequency at which messages are being published in ROS2 ? Lets say if there is no `rate` mentioned.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/301593/how-can-we-know-the-frequency-at-which-messages-are-being-published-in-ros2-?/) by [aks](https://answers.ros.org/users/34222/aks/) on ROS Answers with karma: 667 on 2018-08-25

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The command line tool `ros2 topic hz` is actively being worked on in this PR: https://github.com/ros2/ros2cli/pull/133

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2018-08-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3